# Alignment of two elements in html,css

Tags: javascript, html, css, web, responsive-design

I have the following code:

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Merriweather|Open+Sans');
.blogmaster {
  display: flex;
}

.blogmaster div {
  width: 98.6%;
}

@media all and (max-width: 500px) {
  .blogmaster {flex-flow: wrap;}
}

.container1{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 20px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.square:hover {
    -webkit-transform: translate(20px, -10px);
    -ms-transform: translate(10px, -10px);
    transform: translate(10px, -10px);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 5px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
    box-shadow: 0 5px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
     }


.square{
  width: 460px;
    height: 430px;
    background: white;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: 0px 5px 20px #D9DBDF;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  transition: all 0.3s ease; 
}

.mask{
  clip: rect(0px, 460px, 220px, 0px);
  border-radius: 4px;
  position: absolute;
}

img1{
  width: 560px;
  }

.h11{
  margin: auto;
  text-align: left;
  margin-top: 240px;
  padding-left: 30px;
  padding-right: 30px;
  font-family: 'Merriweather', serif;
  font-size: 24px;
}
p9 {
  text-align: justify;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #C8C8C8;
  line-height: 18px;
  padding-left: 30px;
  padding-right: 30px;
  display: block;
}

.button56 {
    background-color: #3EDD84;
    color: white;
    width: 100px;
    padding: 10px 18px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    margin-top: 15px;
    margin-left: 30px;
    margin-right: 70px;
    font-size: 12px;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-family: 'merriweather';
}
```

```html
<div class="blogmaster">
<div class="column1">
      <div class="row1">
    <div class="container1">
      <div class="square">
        <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1504610926078-a1611febcad3?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=e1c8fe0c9197d66232511525bfd1cc82&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1100&q=80" class="mask" style="border: 5px solid #555">
     <div class="h11">Sample Text Goes here</div>
        <p9>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam in.</p9>
        
     <div><a href="#" target="_" class="button56">Read More</a></div>
      </div>
      </div>
      </div>
      </div>
      </div>
      <!-- new start of blog -->
      <div class="blogmaster">
    <div class="column1">
      <div class="row1">
    <div class="container1">
      <div class="square">
        <img src="https://www.isfasports.gr/image/cache/data/products/pr_3-1100x1100.jpg" class="mask" style="border: 5px solid #555">
     <div class="h11">Sample Text Goes Here</div>
        <p9>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam in.</p9>
        
     <div><a href="#" target="_" class="button56">Read More</a></div>
      </div>
      </div>
      </div>
      </div>
      </div>
```

When you run the above code, open it in a new page, inspect it to view it on a smaller device, **then that is exactly what I am looking for**. (Except, the image's width is a bit wider for some reason, but I can fix it later)

The two cards are algined vertically in responsive mode or when you view it on a smaller device.

The problem now is that when you want to view the cards on a **larger screen, then the cards are still placed vertically, which is not what I want**.

### I am getting this output:

[image]

### Expected Output:

When the user views the cards on a large screen such as a laptop or desktop, then this should be the output:

[image]

On a large screen, they should be placed beside each other with that amount of space between of them as seen in the expected output picture.

But, on a smaller screen, they should be placed vertically, which works fine. So, the only issue is getting the two cards to be beside each other and with that amount of space between them as seen in the expected output picture on a larger screen. Any suggestions?

Comment: The issue cause is `.blogmaster div {width: 98.6%;}`. Change that for larger screens in the `@media` rule. -- By the way, in *Mobile-First*, we use the `@media` rules for the larger screens... Base CSS being for the mobile. ;)

Comment: I added `@media all and (max-width: 1284px) {
.blogmaster div {
  display: flex;
  width: 98.6%;
}
}` but it still places them vertically on large screens

Answer (score 0):

Make parent div with style (display: flex),
then inside parent div make two child div having styles with (width: 50%),
then inside each child div put your cards..

Also you can use or see bootstrap cards and code structure

Comment: Can you show an example with my code above? I have three other cards and I can refer to your code to also make work like that

Comment: Sure!!
let me try

Answer (score 0):

here is your expected result, you have to work on your cards

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Merriweather|Open+Sans');
.blogmaster {
    display: flex;
}

.blogmaster div {
    width: 98.6%;
}

@media all and (max-width: 500px) {
    .blogmaster {
        flex-flow: wrap;
    }
}

.container1 {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    padding: 20px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.square:hover {
    -webkit-transform: translate(20px, -10px);
    -ms-transform: translate(10px, -10px);
    transform: translate(10px, -10px);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 5px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
    box-shadow: 0 5px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
}

.square {
    width: 460px;
    height: 430px;
    background: white;
    border-radius: 4px;
    box-shadow: 0px 5px 20px #D9DBDF;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s ease;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.mask {
    clip: rect(0px, 460px, 220px, 0px);
    border-radius: 4px;
    position: absolute;
}

img1 {
    width: 560px;
}

.h11 {
    margin: auto;
    text-align: left;
    margin-top: 240px;
    padding-left: 30px;
    padding-right: 30px;
    font-family: 'Merriweather', serif;
    font-size: 24px;
}

p9 {
    text-align: justify;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #C8C8C8;
    line-height: 18px;
    padding-left: 30px;
    padding-right: 30px;
    display: block;
}

.button56 {
    background-color: #3EDD84;
    color: white;
    width: 100px;
    padding: 10px 18px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    margin-top: 15px;
    margin-left: 30px;
    margin-right: 70px;
    font-size: 12px;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-family: 'merriweather';
}

.parent-div {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    justify-content: center;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
.parent-div {
    flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="parent-div">
        <div class="child-div">
            <div class="blogmaster">
                <div class="column1">
                    <div class="row1">
                        <div class="container1">
                            <div class="square">
                                <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1504610926078-a1611febcad3?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=e1c8fe0c9197d66232511525bfd1cc82&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1100&q=80"
                                    class="mask" style="border: 5px solid #555">
                                <div class="h11">Sample Text Goes here</div>
                                <p9>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam in.</p9>

                                <div><a href="#" target="_" class="button56">Read More</a></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
        <div class="child-div">

            <div class="blogmaster">
                <div class="column1">
                    <div class="row1">
                        <div class="container1">
                            <div class="square">
                                <img src="https://www.isfasports.gr/image/cache/data/products/pr_3-1100x1100.jpg"
                                    class="mask" style="border: 5px solid #555">
                                <div class="h11">Sample Text Goes Here</div>
                                <p9>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam in.</p9>

                                <div><a href="#" target="_" class="button56">Read More</a></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>

    </div>

    <!-- new start of blog -->

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Now its not displaying it vertically when I inspect it and view it on a smaller screen

Comment: Ok then use style (flexdirection: row) on laptop size screens, and for mobile part add media query, describe in what 'px' you want to make it vertically, and add css style (flexdirection: column) on parent div

Hope you got it !

Comment: Please check, I have updated css code, as an example 
hope all clear now

Comment: What class would I modify to make more space in between the blogs?

Comment: You can use padding